# Can I possibly get shell "echo" or python "print" on a xcode UITableViewCell? (Jailbreak development)

Tags: python, iphone, xcode, uitableview, jailbreak

I am trying to get a Xcode iOS application table to have a table that will make cells on new prints or echoes, then sets the title of the uitableview cell to the print or echo string it has gathered. All help would be appreciated. Im new to this, and have tried everything I could think of. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I use to execute the shell which launches the python script.

```
    -(void)launcechat:(id)sender {
       int result2 = system("sudo sh /Applications/BotVsBot.app/start.sh"); // Executes the requested file (start.sh)
    }
```

Here is the part of the python script that prints what the bots say

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cb1 = Cleverbot()
    cb2 = Cleverbot()

    resp1 = cb1.ask("Hello.")
    print "Bob:", "Hello" 

    while True:
        print "Alice:", resp1
        resp2 = cb2.ask(resp1)
        print "Bob:", resp2
        resp1 = cb1.ask(resp2)
```

Here are the contents of the start.sh file.

```
cd /var/mobile/cleverbot && sudo python cleverbot.py
```

Here are the contents of the install.sh file.

```
sudo apt-get install python -y && sudo apt-get install wget -y && sudo mkdir /var/mobile/cleverbot && cd /var/mobile/cleverbot && sudo wget http://74.63.212.202/wget/cleverbot/cleverbot.py && sudo wget http://74.63.212.202/wget/cleverbot/__init__.py
```

This is the way my python script will output data.

```
Alice: *kicks*.
Bob: *kicks back*.
Alice: *kicks harder*.
Bob: *is kicked harder*.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to write your script output to a file and read it from your app, or post Darwin Notification and receive them in your app.